# Select from Two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables `Table A` and `Table B`.

I want to select the sum columns of each `Code` between two month and year=2017 for TableA as A and TableB as B, but i want select all row from TableB as C where Year=2017 without filter of month.

below what i have tried :

[image]

```
SELECT  A.Annee as Year,  
        code_ville as Code,
        SUM(UniteVendu) AS Unit, 
        SUM(CAVendu) AS CA,  
        SUM(B.UniteVentePrev) AS Unit_P, 
        SUM(B.CAVentePrev) AS Ca_P,
        SUM(C.UniteVentePrev) AS Unit_PPP, 
        SUM(C.CAVentePrev) AS Ca_PPP
 FROM   TableA A 
   left join TableB B on A.code=B.codeP 
                     and  A.Annee=PP.Annee 
                     and A.mois =B.mois    
   left join TableB C on A.code=C.codeP 
                     and A.Annee=C.Annee 
 where  A.Annee = 2017   
 and    A.mois >= 1 
 and    A.mois <= 3  
 GROUP BY  R.Annee, 
           code_ville
```

But I get the incorrect results.

Comment: Is `UNION` not working in this case? You can use UNION to make view by adding extra column to differentiate the TableName.

Comment: Is month the same as mois? You need a union all to combine all the rows from both tables.

Comment: Yes <benjamin> mois as Month

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand your requirements here and if I do they are actually rather simple.  Initially, you need to get your list of `Year` and `Code` combinations so you can build a final results dataset from them, `join`ing into both your `TableA` and `TableB` and doing some conditional `sum` calculations.

*Note that I have added some additional data to display the full functionality of my approach:*

```
-- Built test data
declare @a table([Year] int,[Month] int,Code int, Unit int, CA decimal(20,2));
declare @b table([Year] int,[Month] int,CodeP int, Unit_P int, CA_P decimal(20,0));
insert into @a values (2017,1,280,1,298259.42),(2017,1,281,0,0),(2017,2,280,1,298220.99),(2017,2,281,0,0),(2017,3,282,0,0),(2017,3,280,1,298033.09),(2017,4,280,1,298000.00);
insert into @b values (2017,1,280,1,250000),(2017,1,280,3,950000),(2017,3,281,1,250000),(2017,3,282,1,250000),(2017,6,282,1,250000);

-- Derived table to get all combinations of Year and Code across both tables
with y as
(
    select [Year]
          ,Code
    from @a
    union    -- Use of UNION ensures that a unique list is returned.
    select [Year]
          ,CodeP
    from @b
)
select y.[Year]
      ,y.Code
      ,sum(case when a.[Month] between 1 and 3 then a.Unit else 0 end) as Unit
      ,sum(case when a.[Month] between 1 and 3 then a.CA else 0 end) as CA
      ,sum(case when b.[Month] between 1 and 3 then b.Unit_P else 0 end) as Unit_P
      ,sum(case when b.[Month] between 1 and 3 then b.CA_P else 0 end) as CA_P
      ,isnull(sum(a.Unit),0) as Unit_PPP
      ,isnull(sum(a.CA),0) as CA_PPP
from y  -- Then join this list onto both tables to get the totals
    left join @a a
        on(y.[Year] = a.[Year]
            and y.Code = a.Code
            )
    left join @b b
        on(y.[Year] = b.[Year]
            and y.Code = b.CodeP
            )
group by y.[Year]
        ,y.Code
order by y.[Year]
        ,y.Code;
```

Output:

```
+------+------+------+------------+--------+---------+----------+------------+
| Year | Code | Unit |     CA     | Unit_P |  CA_P   | Unit_PPP |   CA_PPP   |
+------+------+------+------------+--------+---------+----------+------------+
| 2017 |  280 |    6 | 1789027.00 |     16 | 4800000 |        8 | 2385027.00 |
| 2017 |  281 |    0 |       0.00 |      2 |  500000 |        0 |       0.00 |
| 2017 |  282 |    0 |       0.00 |      1 |  250000 |        0 |       0.00 |
+------+------+------+------------+--------+---------+----------+------------+
```